# JS Fullcalendar Update Database

Tags: php, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar, auto-update

I'm using full calendar js and I am able to connect the events created into the database using phpmyadmin however it does not update the database. Here is the codes:

```
<link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   editable: true,
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },

   events: "calendarevents.php",

   // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
   eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
     event.allDay = true;
    } else {
     event.allDay = false;
    }
   },
   selectable: true,
   selectHelper: true,
   select: function(start, end, allDay) {
   var title = prompt('Event Title:');
   var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
   if (title) {
       var start = $.fullCalendar.moment(start).format();
         var end = $.fullCalendar.moment(end).format();
   $.ajax({
   url: 'calendaraddevents.php',
   data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&url='+ url ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
   alert('Added Successfully');
   }
   });
   calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
   {
   title: title,
   start: start,
   end: end,
   allDay: allDay
   },
   true // make the event "stick"
   );
   }
   calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
   },

   editable: true,
   eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.moment(start).format();
   var end = $.fullCalendar.moment(end).format();
   $.ajax({
   url: 'calendarupdateevents.php',
   data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start='+ start +'&end=' + end + '&id=' + event.id ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {   
    alert("Updated Successfully");
   }
   });
   },
   eventResize: function(event) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.moment(start).format();
   var end = $.fullCalendar.moment(end).format();
   $.ajax({
    url: 'calendarupdateevents.php',
    data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&id=' + event.id ,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(json) {
     alert("Updated Successfully");
    }
   });

}

  });

 }); 
</script>
```

Here is the codes for calendarupdateevents.php

```
<?php
/* Values received via ajax */
$id = $_POST['id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];

// connection to the database
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ththy', 'calendar', '1234');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
// update the records
$sql = "UPDATE evenement SET title=?, start=?, end=? WHERE id=?";
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
?>
```

Comment: You aren't passing any parameters to your parameterised query. It's worth returning a response from the PHP script, perhaps using JSON - there are a lot of things that can go wrong in a database, and it is worth getting a success/fail value your frontend code can make use of.

Comment: thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As halfer said, you aren't passing any parameters to your query.
Try this :

```
<?php
/* Values received via ajax */
$values = array(
    'id' => int($_POST['id']),
    'title' => htmlentities($_POST['title'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8"),
    'start' => htmlentities($_POST['start'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8"),
    'end' => htmlentities($_POST['end'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8")
);
// connection to the database
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ththy', 'calendar', '1234');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
// update the records
$sql = "UPDATE evenement SET title=?, start=?, end=? WHERE id=?";
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute($values);
?>
```

Comment: @coding18: did this work? If so, consider upvoting, or accepting to mark as correct (to do the latter, click the tick mark so that it turns green). Thanks!

Comment: This is a good answer except that the database update is generally considered the wrong place for `htmlentities()`. That XSS protection is a good idea but should go in the template/view rendering - since in some cases, if you want to store HTML and are sure that it is safe, you want to be able to print it out in raw form i.e. without converting it to entities.

Answer (score 0):

The example is not returning the correct limits of the event. To return the event start-end moments, I suggest:

```
    var start = event.start.format();
    var end = event.end.format();
```